# Security of sending sensitive intent extras within my own app?

Tags: android, security, application-security

I have an activity which asks for a username and password, then starts another activity in my app to complete a user signup. I want to send the username+password as intent extras to the second activity. Something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("u", username);
intent.putExtra("p", password);
startActivity(intent);
```

and my manifest defines SecondActivity like:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.me.SecondActivity"
   android:label="">
   <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
      android:value="com.me.FirstActivity" />
</activity>
```

and now I'm having doubts about the security of sending the username+password as intent extras like this - is it possible for another app to intercept the invocation of SecondActivity with a spoofed intent filter? Besides that, I wonder what happens with the intent extras, are they ever persisted to disk by the OS? Someone might be able to look at them there if so.

Thanks

Comment: As you are specifying the Activity to launch directly I am pretty sure that you are by passing any form of IntentFilters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key here is the distinction between **Implicit Intents** and **Explicit Intents**.  Your example uses an Explicit Intent as your are specifying the exact class your want to run. This is fine, because Explicit Intents cannot be intercepted and will stay within your application.

Implicit Intents however, open up several possible attack vectors. [This article](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2013/05/13/android-security/) talks about it in more detail. I would very much recommend against using Implicit Intents to pass any kind of sensitive information.

From the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

> Explicit Intents have specified a component (via setComponent(ComponentName) or setClass(Context, Class)), which provides the exact class to be run.
>
> Implicit Intents have not specified a component; instead, they must include enough information for the system to determine which of the available components is best to run for that intent.

As I stated, for your example in the question, passing the password via Intent is relatively secure in that no other application can intercept it at runtime. But it is important to note that this is not always the case, and using implicit Intents could theoretically allow Intent Interception and expose the sensitive information.

**Edit**:

As for persisting the Intent Extras to the disk, yes this is a risk. Keep in mind however, that if someone has root access on the device and is using it to try to search the disk for this persisted intent information, there may be easier ways for them to get the same information. No matter what you do, someone with root access to the physical device will probably be able to get that password off unless you do some very excellent encryption.

My recommendation on a overall security perspective is to try not to deal with passwords directly in any kind of long term or persistent context. Passwords should only be used during a log in process and discarded immediately afterwards (assuming you are authenticating with a server). Therefore, with the normal use of the application (a legitimate user with a real password), you don't have to worry about a malicious actor inspecting the device memory, because by the time the malicious actor gets a hold of the device, the password has long sense been removed from memory.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for third-party apps to intercept system-wide intents. I suggest encrypting your data before sending it to the next intent, and then decrypting it once it has been received.

Comment: Could you please point out how it is working to intercept explicit intents.

Comment: Mark Murphy wrote an excellent short summary: [Warning: Activity Intent Extras Can Be Public](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/30/warning-activity-intent-extras-public.html)

Answer (score 0):

Handling passwords should always be a very short term affair. It's recommended to use them only for authentication request and then discard them. Coming to specifics of your question, i.e., sending password between activities through an explicit intent, this is secure to the extent that no other app will be able to intercept it and view the value. However, the passwords value needs to be maintained somewhere (memory or disk) in order to pass it to your secondary activity. If it's maintained on the disk it's pretty easy to retrieve. If its maintained in memory, an attacker who gets access to your device can root it and then perform memory dump to view the values in the memory. Thus it is not recommended to deal with passwords in this fashion.

Comment: Also, the intent "extras" can be read by accessing baseIntent object of RecentTaskInfo (readable by any app with GET_TASKS permission). Although this is now deprecated, it works on older versions.